# Access contained UIView component from Parent ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my parent viewcontroller, I have a view container, I added a subview to it:

```
    m_cardDetail  = [[CardDetailView alloc] init];
    [_m_viewContainer addSubview:m_cardDetail];
    [m_cardDetail initialize];
```

But how can I let my parent viewcontroller process a button click (button resides in m_cardDetail subview). I tried setting the button tag property of the button to 1010 and using this code in parent viewcontroller:

```
    UIButton *aButtonView = (UIButton *)[m_cardDetail viewWithTag:1010];
    [aButtonView addTarget:self action:@selector(aButtonTapped:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and also added this in viewcontroller:

```
    - (void) aButtonTapped:(UIButton *) sender {
        //Do something
    }
```

but im getting the Unrecognized selector error

Comment: You can do a custom delegate to do that. [like in this article](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002)

Answer (score 1):

You should treat another view controller's views as private, even one that is a child view controller. As @Ostanik suggests in his answer (voted), setting up a protocol and a delegate is a good way to make a connection between a parent and child.

Note that an embed segue is a very clean way to set up the parent/child link. You simply create a container view in IB and control-drag from the container view to the scene of the view controller that you want to be a child, and Xcode does the rest. When the parent view controller is loaded the embed segue is invoked and you can set up the delegate in your prepareForSegue method.